# Knockout.js 2.2.1 can't find observable array

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Not sure what's going wrong here, but KnockoutJS is having some issues finding my observable array that's inside my `MasterViewModel`. Using `2.2.1` with jQuery `1.8.x` as well as not my first KJS app. Here it is:

**Initialize**

```
$(function() {
  window.vm = new MasterViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

**ViewModel**

```
function MasterViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.currentAppView = ko.observable();

  // Users
  self.userList = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.templateListGetter = ko.computed(function() {
    $.getJSON("/user/list"), function(data) {
      var mapped = $.map(data, function(item) { return new userModel(item) });
      self.userList(mapped);
    };
  });

  self.goToAppView = function(appView) { 
    location.hash = '!/' + appView;
  };    
  Sammy(function() {
      this.get('#!/:appView', function() {
        self.currentAppView(this.params.appView);
        $('.appview').hide();
        ko.applyBindings(new window[this.params.appView+'VM']());
      });
      this.notFound = function(){
        location.hash = "!/dashboard";
      }
      //this.raise_errors = true;
  }).run();
}
```

**The View**

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: userList">
      <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: guid"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: updated"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: suspended"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I have a simple table that I am loading

Even after double-checking a couple things like adding `defer="defer"` to my JS tag and ensuring the `userList` exists, it simply cannot find the observableArray. It gives the error:

```
Message: ReferenceError: userList is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: userList Error {}
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

### Update

For those wondering what gets called every time the hash changes:

```
function usersVM() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    // Behaviours
    $('#users').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're initializing knockout with an undefined viewmodel?

`ko.applyBindings(new window[this.params.appView+'VM']());`, yet your actual viewmodel is `window.vm`. Case sensitivity ftw. Also, the viewmodel on window is already created / initialized. So you don't need the `new` operator.

So, change the applyBindings line to be

`ko.applyBindings(window[this.params.appView+'vm']());`

### Updated Answer: By Poster

There was no necessity to keep running `ko.applyBindings` every time the route changed since it was already applying bindings on page load. So Sammy.js was changed to:

```
  Sammy(function() {
      this.get('#!/:appView', function() {
        self.currentAppView(this.params.appView);
        $('.appview').hide();
        window[this.params.appView+'Route']();
      });
      this.notFound = function(){
        location.hash = "!/dashboard";
      }
      //this.raise_errors = true;
  }).run();
```

It does look like `ko.computed` or a regular function call to `window.vm.getUserList()` isn't running properly, but this will be saved for a different question.

```
function usersRoute() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    // Behaviours
    $('#users').show();
    window.vm.getUserList();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm didn't solve the problem sadly. My apologies, I chose a poor name for the `VM` params. It actually references different functions to be performed when the "page" changes. Updating Question.

Comment: Ok you were partially right, but it looks like there are two problems. I am going to edit your answer with what was changed ;)

Comment: okay. The other thing that I just noticed is that you were probably overwriting the MasterVM with the sub VM. I'm super pumped to see what the actual problem was!